# Using Series to expand solution of an equation

Tags: series-expansion

How can I tell *Mathematica* to keep solutions of this equation up to second order in q?

```
Solve[Det[{{I x + a, b, 0}, {I f - I q^2 O, 
     I x + d - q^2 c, -I q^2 e}, {0, h, I x + g}}] == 0, x]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = x /.Solve[Det[{{I x + a, b, 0}, {I f - I q^2 O, 
   I x + d - q^2 c, -I q^2 e}, {0, h, I x + g}}] == 0, x]

Normal[Series[sol, {q, 0, 2}]]
```